# How can I create an array of multi-elemented objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I want to make an array of `Instruction`, an object that takes an `int` and two `Vector3`s. I'm aware of how to make arrays, but I'm not sure how to create an array of multi-elemented objects, if at all possible. I.E.

```
int[] myInts = new int[] {1, 4, 1, 5}; //Creates an array of ints
```

BUT

```
Instruction[] instructions = new Instruction[] { 
    {1, new Vector3(1, 5, 2), new Vector3(4, 1, 7)} 
    {2, new Vector3(6, 2, 7), new Vector3(9, 7, 4)}
}
```

Is that how you do it, or is it different?

Comment: You call the `Instruction` constructor?

Comment: Ahhh, I'm a big baka...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must specify the `new` keyword and type:

```
Instruction[] instructions = new Instruction[] { 
    new Instruction {1, new Vector3(1, 5, 2), new Vector3(4, 1, 7)}, //And add comma
    new Instruction {2, new Vector3(6, 2, 7), new Vector3(9, 7, 4)}
};
```

Have a look at [MSDN Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: downvoter please explain?.....

Comment: So I explicitly need to use the curly brackets when using the constructor, as opposed to using regular parentheses?

Comment: @Shadowtail - yap. That is the syntax in C#